# IPMI watchdog pre-timeout interrupt on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, intel, platform, watchdog

I tried to enable watchdog through IPMI on FreeBSD 7.

According to IPMI spec v2.0. It's able to set NMI interrupt by set pre-timeout action bit.
The timeout action returns correct, but there is no response with NMI interrupt.
I wander whether it need other configuration somewhere else.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeBSD watchdogd daemon is what you want. It initialises correspondent device (ichwd or amdsbwd - it should show up in your dmesg if you had enabled it) or uses software watchdog.

Comment: Thanks, It seems the current version of BIOS not supporting the NMI signal. After fresh the firmware, It worked~ Thanks for answering~